# How to display blog post description structured correctly for a Django blog?

Tags: python, django, post, django-templates, blogs

I am creating a blog where it displays the post description in a blog post. But the post data is displaying odd or continues text. I want post description to display same in a proper format that is given as an input.

In Urls.py

```
path('blog_single/<str:title>/', views.blog_single, name = 'blog_single'),
```

---

In Views.py

```
def blog_single(request, title):
    posts = Post.objects.get(title = title)
    recent_posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-posted_at')[:5]
    Categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'posts':posts, 'recent_posts':recent_posts , 'Categories': Categories}
    return render(request, 'blog-single.html', context)
```

---

In blog-single.html

```
          <div class="entry-img">
            <img src="{{posts.thumbnail.url}}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
          </div>

          <h2 class="entry-title">
            <a href="#">{{posts.title}}</a>
          </h2>

          <div class="entry-meta">
            <ul>
              <li class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="bi bi-person"></i> <a href="blog-single.html">{{posts.user}}</a></li>
              <li class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="bi bi-clock"></i> <a href="blog-single.html"><time datetime="2020-01-01">{{posts.posted_at}}</time></a></li>
              <!-- <li class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="bi bi-chat-dots"></i> <a href="blog-single.html">12 Comments</a></li> -->
              <li class="d-flex align-items-center"><i class="bi bi-list"></i> <a href="blog-single.html">{{posts.category}}</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="entry-content">
            <p class="post__description">
              {{posts.description|safe}}
            </p>

          </div>

          <div class="entry-footer">
            <i class="bi bi-folder"></i>
            <ul class="cats">
              <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
            </ul>

            <i class="bi bi-tags"></i>
            <ul class="tags">
              <li><a href="#">Creative</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Tips</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Marketing</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </article><!-- End blog entry -->
```

---

In Models.py file

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'categories')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users')

    title = models.CharField(max_length =255)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'post/thumbnail')

    description = models.TextField()
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    posted_at = models.DateField(default = datetime.now)  
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default = False)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Post")
        verbose_name_plural = ('Posts')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```